# Opening the linear regression black box

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, polynomial

How does LinearRegression fit polynomials? I am not sure why I have to pass to the `fit` an array of the data where every point has been converted to Nth order features, instead of simply passing the original data alongside the degree N.

```
lr = LinearRegression()
pr = PolynomialFeatures(degree=N)
x_train_pr = pr.fit_transform(x_train[['a']])  
lr.fit(x_train_pr, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regression fits the model

$$(1) \ \ y = \theta_1 z_1 + ... \theta_K z_K + \epsilon$$

where $z_1,...,z_K$ are data - you can call them "features" if you want - and $\theta_1,...,\theta_K$ are parameters to be estimated, $\epsilon$ is unobserved error and $y$ is observed output variable.

In polynomial regression the model is

$$(2) \ \ y = \theta_1 + \theta_2 x + \theta_3 x^2 +...+ \theta_K x^{K-1} + \epsilon$$

so obviously if you create variable $z_1=1$ and $z_2=x$ and $z_3=x^2$ etc. the model (2) model can be fitted using the same procedure as used for model (1).

So linear regression fits polynomials by finding values for $\theta_1,...,\theta_K$ when someone uses an array of the data $z$ where every point has been converted to k'th order features.

The solution for estimates are found using the Ordinary Least Squares estimator.